# Как расширить input text в зависимости от его значения value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Мне нужен инпут который будет расширяться в зависимости от его value. Сейчас я сделал такой `Codepen` https://codepen.io/fad90/pen/qBPOZeG
Однако мне нужно чтобы его ширина в пустом виде была, примерно 2px и после того как я начну печатать она начинала увеличиваться пропорционально веденому value. Сейчас же я не могу сделать ширину пустого инпута еще меньше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также сейчас когда я печатаю, то справа от моего текста остается достаточно большое пространство.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как мне решить данные проблемы. Или может есть другой способ сделать такое инпут поле?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить как вариант для вашего примера

```html
<input
  className='input'
  type="text"
  value={input}
  onChange={changeHandler}
  size={input.length>1?input.length - 1:1}
/>
```

Comment: добавлю только - нужно контролировать ширину, чтобы инпут не вылез за пределы родителя

Comment: А как инпут с пустым value сделать еще меньше? (например 2px)